# Is there an instrument which can show the magnetic field in a region?

Tags: magnetic-fields, instrument

I know that an instrument called [magnetometer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer#:%7E:text=A%20magnetometer%20is%20a%20device,field%20at%20a%20particular%20location.) exists. But it can only measure the magnetic field at a given point. I wonder if there exist, or is it possible to build a device which would be able to show the magnetic field present in a given region on a digital screen.

Something like a infrared scanner (below) but for magnetic fields.

[image: IR Scanner]

Comment: An infrared scanner is still only measuring electromagnetic fields at the point of the sensor, and reconstructing the field from that. To do so for the magnetic field would require a solution of Maxwell's equations subject to the boundary conditions your sensor data imposes, or otherwise a fitting if your sensor data to the expected shape of magnetic field.

Comment: There are optical methods that measure atomic levels interacting with magnetic fields, and can be deployed to look at a volume. But only in fairly limited circumstances...

Comment: Since you clank down on other attempts to give an answer, I hesitate to mention green magnetic viewing film or the AR (augmented reality) mobile phone apps.

Comment: @Pieter  I am not sure that could be called an answer. The very purpose of SE is to be precise and to the point and not flippant like Reddit. I have made my question clear and if there is any doubt I will clear it. I am looking for a proper answer, not sass from high ranking members just because they can. I would also like to know more about the AR apps and the green magnetic viewing film you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to see magnetic field strength in astronomy by using the Zeeman effect in atomic emission lines. This works very well for the [surface of the Sun](http://www.lund.irf.se/HeliosHome/observemagfield.html). The direction of the field can be deduced from polarization.

In a comment I mentioned Augmented Reality. There are quite amazing apps for that. There is an example in the Physics Toolbox Suite, which I tried out today to get the image below. There is a current of a few amperes through the coil of that loop antenna.

[image: Screen capture]

(They also have a [specialized app](http://magna-ar.net/), but that did not work for me.)

The [green viewing film](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Magnetic_field_viewing_film) that I mentioned is just the same principle as the classic iron filings.

Comment: Although I'm sure you know from using the app (and are answering what the OP wants, because as indicated in the comments, he was interested in AR apps), I want to emphasize to others that this app is *not* measuring the magnetic field at a distance away. Instead, you carry the phone through the space, and press when you want to measure the field. When you tap, the phone will use the on-board magnetometer to measure the field at that point. After, you can pull your phone back to view the field arrows at the points you've collected.